# What is the maximum number of digits that can be stored in a .NET numeric data type

Tags: .net, rsa

This is just out of curiosity. We know that for cryptology applications two large prime numbers (of more than 100 digits) are multiplied to form a part of the public key. So which Microsoft.NET number type can store the largest prime numbers, of hundreds of digits ? In other words which numeric data type can accommodate the largest whole number in .NET ? I understand that System.Double which uses 8 bytes, can store a max value of  (1.79769313486232 × 10^308) -  this probably accommodates 309 digits. However, System.Decimal uses 16 bytes and can store a max of 79228162514264337593543950335 which is only 29 decimal digits (lesser digits than Double ?)

Thanks,
Chak.

Comment: "What Every Computer Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic" - http://blogs.sun.com/darcy/resource/Wecpskafpa-StanfordIcme500.pdf

Comment: For RSA you need the less significant digits too(you're doing integer calculations modulo n), so you can't use any floating-point type(Double,Decimal,...) but need a big enough integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using .NET 4, have a look at [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) which can store arbitrarily large integers.

`double` does *not* store 309 digits - it has a wide *range*, but it only has 15-16 digits of precision. In other words, if you convert large `long` values (e.g. those just below `long.MaxValue`) to `double` and back you'll lose information. See my articles on [binary](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx) and [decimal](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) floating point types for more information.

Comment: Thanks. This is an Out of thread question- if one is preparing for the 70-536 .NET Framework Foundation exam we will not be aware of System.Numerics.BigInteger, which you pointed out. Is there an updated exam for .NET 4 ?

Comment: @Chakra: I have no idea, I'm afraid. I don't really "do" certification.