# What is BigInteger and when would we use that?

Tags: .net

What is BigInteger and when would we use that ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a struct for an arbitrarily large integer, introduced in .NET 4.

You'd use it when you want to represent integers larger than `Int64`/`UInt64` can cope with. For example, yesterday I wrote [some code to normalize `System.Decimal` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298719/parse-decimal-and-filter-extra-0-on-the-right/4298787#4298787). `System.Decimal` uses a 96-bit integer to represent its mantissa, but I wanted to work with it as an integer - so I used `BigInteger`.

(It's possible that I could have taken another approach just using `decimal`, but that's a different matter...)

As another example, there was a [question asked just 45 minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302116) about representing large integers to work with them for cryptography purposes. While *real* crypto algorithms probably use something more specialized and efficient, using `BigInteger` to multiply large integers together etc is a good way of showing what logically happens in crypto code.

Comment: There's no upper limit in case of BigInteger?

Answer (score 1):

[BigInteger on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

The BigInteger type is an immutable type that represents an arbitrarily large integer whose value **in theory has no upper or lower bounds.** The members of the BigInteger type closely parallel those of other integral types (the Byte, Int16, Int32, Int64, SByte, UInt16, UInt32, and UInt64 types). This type differs from the other integral types in the .NET Framework, which have a range indicated by their MinValue and MaxValue properties.